# Hadoop MapReduce: context.write changes values

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new to Hadoop and writing MapReduce jobs and I am encountering a problem where it appears reducers context.write method is changing correct values into incorrect ones.

**What is MapReduce job supposed to do?**

- Count the total number of words `(int wordCount)`
- Count the number of distinct words `(int counter_dist)`
- Count the number of words starting with "z" or "Z" `(int counter_startZ)`
- Count the number of words that appear less than 4 times `(int counter_less4)`

*All of this must be done in a single MapReduce job.*

**Text file being analysed**

```
Hello how zou zou zou zou how are you
```

***Correct output:***
`wordCount = 9`
`counter_dist = 5`
`counter_startZ = 4`
`counter_less4 = 4`

**Mapper Class**

```
public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper <Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    @Override
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String hasKey = itr.nextToken();
            word.set(hasKey);
            context.write(word, one);
        }

    }
}
```

**Reducer Class**
In order to debug my code, I printed out a lot of statements to check my values at every point. Stdout code is available below.

```
public class WordCountReducer extends Reducer <Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    int wordCount = 0; // Total number of words
    int counter_dist = 0; // Number of distinct words in the corpus
    int counter_startZ = 0; // Number of words that start with letter Z
    int counter_less4 = 0; // Number of words that appear less than 4 

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int repeatedWords = 0;
        System.out.println("###Reduce method starts");
        System.out.println("Values: wordCount:" + wordCount + " counter_dist:" + counter_dist + " counter_startZ:" + counter_startZ + " counter_less4:" + counter_less4 + " (start)");
        for (IntWritable val : values){
            System.out.println("Key: " + key.toString());
            repeatedWords++;
            wordCount += val.get();
            if(key.toString().startsWith("z") || key.toString().startsWith("Z")){
            counter_startZ++;
            }
            System.out.println("Values: wordCount:" + wordCount + " counter_dist:" + counter_dist + " counter_startZ:" + counter_startZ + " counter_less4:" + counter_less4 + " (end of loop)");
        }
        counter_dist++;

        if(repeatedWords < 4){
            counter_less4++;
        }

        System.out.println("Values: wordCount:" + wordCount + " counter_dist:" + counter_dist + " counter_startZ:" + counter_startZ + " counter_less4:" + counter_less4 + " repeatedWords:" + repeatedWords + " (end)");
        System.out.println("###Reduce method ends\n");
    }


    @Override
    public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("###CLEANUP: wordCount: " + wordCount);
        System.out.println("###CLEANUP: counter_dist: " + counter_dist);
        System.out.println("###CLEANUP: counter_startZ: " + counter_startZ);
        System.out.println("###CLEANUP: counter_less4: " + counter_less4);

        context.write(new Text("Total words: "), new IntWritable(wordCount));
        context.write(new Text("Distinct words: "), new IntWritable(counter_dist));
        context.write(new Text("Starts with Z: "), new IntWritable(counter_startZ));
        context.write(new Text("Appears less than 4 times:"), new IntWritable(counter_less4));
    }


}
```

**Stdout log, which I am using for debugging**

```
###Reduce method starts
Values: wordCount:0 counter_dist:0 counter_startZ:0 counter_less4:0 (start)
Key: Hello
Values: wordCount:1 counter_dist:0 counter_startZ:0 counter_less4:0 (end of loop)
Values: wordCount:1 counter_dist:1 counter_startZ:0 counter_less4:1 repeatedWords:1 (end)
###Reduce method ends

###Reduce method starts
Values: wordCount:1 counter_dist:1 counter_startZ:0 counter_less4:1 (start)
Key: are
Values: wordCount:2 counter_dist:1 counter_startZ:0 counter_less4:1 (end of loop)
Values: wordCount:2 counter_dist:2 counter_startZ:0 counter_less4:2 repeatedWords:1 (end)
###Reduce method ends

###Reduce method starts
Values: wordCount:2 counter_dist:2 counter_startZ:0 counter_less4:2 (start)
Key: how
Values: wordCount:3 counter_dist:2 counter_startZ:0 counter_less4:2 (end of loop)
Key: how
Values: wordCount:4 counter_dist:2 counter_startZ:0 counter_less4:2 (end of loop)
Values: wordCount:4 counter_dist:3 counter_startZ:0 counter_less4:3 repeatedWords:2 (end)
###Reduce method ends

###Reduce method starts
Values: wordCount:4 counter_dist:3 counter_startZ:0 counter_less4:3 (start)
Key: you
Values: wordCount:5 counter_dist:3 counter_startZ:0 counter_less4:3 (end of loop)
Values: wordCount:5 counter_dist:4 counter_startZ:0 counter_less4:4 repeatedWords:1 (end)
###Reduce method ends

###Reduce method starts
Values: wordCount:5 counter_dist:4 counter_startZ:0 counter_less4:4 (start)
Key: zou
Values: wordCount:6 counter_dist:4 counter_startZ:1 counter_less4:4 (end of loop)
Key: zou
Values: wordCount:7 counter_dist:4 counter_startZ:2 counter_less4:4 (end of loop)
Key: zou
Values: wordCount:8 counter_dist:4 counter_startZ:3 counter_less4:4 (end of loop)
Key: zou
Values: wordCount:9 counter_dist:4 counter_startZ:4 counter_less4:4 (end of loop)
Values: wordCount:9 counter_dist:5 counter_startZ:4 counter_less4:4 repeatedWords:4 (end)
###Reduce method ends

###CLEANUP: wordCount: 9
###CLEANUP: counter_dist: 5
###CLEANUP: counter_startZ: 4
###CLEANUP: counter_less4: 4
```

From the log it appears like all the values are correct and that everything works fine. However, when I open the output directory in HDFS and read the "part-r-00000" file, the output from the context.write which is written there is completely different.

```
Total words: 22
Distinct words: 4
Starts with Z: 0
Appears less than 4 times: 4
```

Comment: I have added the complete code logic. Hope you understand it. Let me know.

Comment: It seems like a strange thing ，had you try debug your code  .to see the variables !

Answer (score 1):

You must never rely on `cleanup()` method for crucial program logic. The `cleanup()` method is called every time a JVM is ripped off. So based on the number of JVM (which you can not predict) spawned and killed, your logic become volatile.

Move the `initialization` and writing to context both into reduce method.

i.e.

```
int wordCount = 0; // Total number of words
int counter_dist = 0; // Number of distinct words in the corpus
int counter_startZ = 0; // Number of words that start with letter Z
int counter_less4 = 0; // Number of words that appear less than 4
```

and

```
   context.write(new Text("Total words: "), new IntWritable(wordCount));
    context.write(new Text("Distinct words: "), new IntWritable(counter_dist));
    context.write(new Text("Starts with Z: "), new IntWritable(counter_startZ));
    context.write(new Text("Appears less than 4 times:"), new IntWritable(counter_less4));
```

---

**EDIT : Based on OP comments, it seems that whole logic is flawed.**

Below is the code to accomplish the desired result. **Please note that, I have not implemented `setup()` or `cleanup()`; because that is not at all needed.**

Use counters to count what you are looking for. After MapReduce completes, just fetch the counters in the driver class.

e.g. **Number of words** and **words starting with "z" or "Z"** can be counted in the mapper

```
public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper <Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    @Override
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String hasKey = itr.nextToken();
            word.set(hasKey);
            context.getCounter("my_counters", "TOTAL_WORDS").increment(1);
            if(hasKey.toUpperCase().startsWith("Z")){
            context.getCounter("my_counters", "Z_WORDS").increment(1);
            }
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
}
```

The **Number of distinct words** and `words appearing less than 4 times` can be counted in reducer counter.

```
public class WordCountReducer extends Reducer <Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int wordCount= 0;
        context.getCounter("my_counters", "DISTINCT_WORDS").increment(1);
        for (IntWritable val : values){
            wordCount += val.get();
        }
        if(wordCount < 4{
           context.getCounter("my_counters", "WORDS_LESS_THAN_4").increment(1);
        }
    }
}
```

In the Driver class fetch the counters. The below code goes after the line where you have submitted the job

```
CounterGroup group = job.getCounters().getGroup("my_counters");

for (Counter counter : group) {
   System.out.println(counter.getName() + "=" + counter.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not what I am looking for. I need only 4 lines in the output with correctly counted values ("correct output" in the question). This solution adds 4 lines to the output every time it runs reduce method.

Comment: You are making fundamental mistake by writing your code logic in `cleanup` method. You must understand about role of `setup` and `cleanup` method specially when hadoop spawn a new JVM for each reducer. If the above fix does not work, it means your logic needs to be changed.